# wp_query comment and meta query

Tags: wp-query

I making wp_query that control comment-count, and meta key value. 
So, I coded like this. but is doesn't work. When I use comment_cout only or meta_query only, it works good. when I use together, it doesn't work normally. 
Can I get some help? Thank you.

```
<?php
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'race',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'comment_count' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 10,
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        // 'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'race_date',
            'value'   => $today, //this is get by php time() function. ex) 2018-12-10
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'comment_count' => 'DESC',                           
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $arg );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $postid = get_the_ID();

        the_title();
        echo '<br />';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks ok. I recommend `var_dump($query->request);` and take a look at the generated SQL. I don't think it will change anything but I always add `"TYPE"=>"DATE"` as an argument when I do a date based meta query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you recommended, I did var_dump. it says.. " 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'race_date' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= '2018-12-05' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'race' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.comment_count DESC LIMIT 0, 5' " but, I don't know well about SQL well....

Comment: There you go. The query doesn't pick up comment_count because as @JacobPeattie notes below, the comment_count clause not a nested array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline documentation of `WP_Query` has this:

> Filter results by comment count. Provide an integer to match comment count exactly. Provide an array with integer 'value' and 'compare' operator ('=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=' ) to compare against comment_count in a specific way.

So there should only be one array, not 2 like with a meta query:

```
'comment_count' => array(
    'value'   => 10,
    'compare' => '>=',
),
```